# Peripheral.setMTU(244) but can get only 20 bytes

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, mtu

I want to read more than 20 bytes of data from bluetooth to raspberry pi 3b+.
I override `DefaultDelegate` and `handleNotification(cHandle, data)`, and get data from `handleNotification(cHandle, data)`. 
Then I convert type of data from byte to hex, and I can only get 20 bytes of data.

Here is my code:

```
dev = btle.Peripheral(address, 'random')
dev.setMTU(244)
```

My BLE peripheral device is "Nordic NRF52832".
How can I get more than 20 bytes of data?

Answer (score 2):

Adding delay worked for me :

```
dev = btle.Peripheral(address, 'random')
import time
time.sleep(1)
dev.setMTU(244)
```

source:
https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy/issues/325

Answer (score 0):

I think I find the reason of it. 
Library `bluepy` supports `BLE4.0` but don't support `BLE4.2`.
`BLE4.0` and `BLE4.1` can get the payload for only 20 bytes.

Comment: MTU has nothing to do with Bluetooth version. In fact, Bluetooth 4.0 supports 64 KB MTU.

Comment: @Emil I think BLE is different from normal Bluetooth, is it?

Comment: Yes it's a completely different radio protocol.

Comment: @Emil Do BLE4.0 supports more than 20 bytes of payload data?

Comment: In Bluetooth 4.0, the BLE Link Layer supports up to 27 bytes payload per packet. In version 4.2 LE Data Length Extension was introduced which increases the maximum payload size of the Link Layer to 251 bytes (must be negotiated between the two devices). The link layer payload size is irrelevant and transparent to the application. To the application only the ATT MTU is relevant and all BLE versions support ATT MTU up to 65535 bytes. The devices however need to negotiate a max MTU if you want to use an MTU higher of 23 (which is default). So it's possible your peripheral sticks to default MTU.